# When running "ng serve --watch" how does the browser know when to refresh when there is any change to the sources?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular-cli 1.6.5 node 6.9.1. I'm running my app using the following command:

> ng serve --watch

When I make changes to my typescript or HTML sources (e.g. app.component.ts), the browser automatically refreshes.

**My question is, how does the browser know when to refresh?** I don't see any requests being sent out from the browser to the app and vice versa. And I couldn't see network traffic on my browser other than when the page refreshes.

For clarity, my question is not about how Angular detects changes on DOM elements or model objects bound to it.

Comment: I would assume it uses web sockets

Comment: @CUGreen, you're right. I just check every response and there's one with instruction to switch to websocket.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Web Sockets.

`ng serve` starts a server which watches for file changes and sends a web socket message to the client with a new hash.

By making the network slower in chrome dev tools we will be able to see the websocket messages as they are sent to the browser:

[image]

Make a file change:

[image]

Comment: Cool! More than what I needed!